# If $f_k \rightarrow f$ a.e. on $E$ and $|E|$ is finite, then $f_k \rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $f$ and $f_k$, $k = 1, 2, \ldots$, be measurable and finite a.e. in $E$. If $f_k \rightarrow f$ a.e. on $E$ and $|E| < +\infty$, then $f_k \rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$.

My proof is as follows: given $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f_k \rightarrow f$ a.e. on $E$, we have $$\{|f - f_k| \leq \epsilon \} \nearrow E$$ So $$|\{|f - f_k| \leq \epsilon \}| \rightarrow |E|$$ Note that $\{|f - f_k| > \epsilon \} = E  - \{|f - f_k| \leq \epsilon \}$.

And since $|E| < \infty$, we have $$|\{|f - f_k| > \epsilon \}| = |E|  - |\{|f - f_k| \leq \epsilon \}| \rightarrow 0$$ Hence $f_k \rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $\lbrace |f-f_k|\leq \epsilon\rbrace$ need not be increasing in $k$.